# How to ensure Absolute URL redirect for A href

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I am trying to add an absolute external link into a JSP page in a Spring/JSP app e.g.:

```
<a href ="www.google.com" id="summaryLink" class="table-data">Summaries</a>
```

The problem is that this does not redirect to http://www.google.com, instead it redirects to http://localhost:8081/myappp/www.google.com. Is there a way to redirect to the absolute URL only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify protocol:

```
<a href ="http://www.google.com" id="summaryLink" class="table-data">Summaries</a>
```

or

```
<a href ="https://www.google.com" id="summaryLink" class="table-data">Summaries</a>
```

or you can use // for same protocol as the one used for current page

```
<a href ="//www.google.com" id="summaryLink" class="table-data">Summaries</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://` like:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="summaryLink" class="table-data">Summaries</a>
```

check: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oLptcnoq/):